# When to use MVC Scaffolding via NuGet vs MVC Scaffolding via MVC3 Tools Update

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, scaffolding

I am a little confused about the various different "mainstream" scaffolding options for MVC3.  There is a NuGet package called [MVCScaffolding](http://nuget.org/packages/MVCScaffolding). It first showed up in Jan 2011, but seems to be active and have recent updates, and be developed by Scott Hanselman, among others. Then in May 2011 came the [MVC3 Tools Update](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx).  This *seems* like it incorporated the original scaffolding ideas into an "out of the box" scaffolding options.  However, this has not been updated since.

So - what is the relationship between these two scaffoldings (if any). Are there cases when one should be used over the other, or is it just a matter of taste?  Does Visual Studio 2012 or MVC4 change the game on any of this?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Just googled the same question and found your post. what a coincidence. Joining to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my investigations so far:

**MVCScaffolding**:

- Designed to use the Code First EF implementation*, with DBContext data context & POCO models
- Provides a very fast way to create an MVC web app build using the Repository data access pattern

**MVC3 Tools Scaffolding**

- A way to create Controllers and Views for a model, using either the EF Database First, or EF Code First approach
- The Controllers it creates use the data context directly (as opposed to via a data access abstraction like a Repository)

*There is [a way to get the MVCScaffolding working with Database First](http://weblogs.asp.net/paullitwin/archive/2011/08/11/use-mvc-scaffolding-in-database-first-mode.aspx), but you have to work it a little.

**My Conclusions (subjective)**

- Code First, use MVCScaffolding.
- Database First, use MVC3 Tools scaffolding.

Overall, the Code First & MVC3 Scaffolding seems a more "best practice" approach.  The Repository creates more clean opportunities for unit tests, and the POCOs mean there is not data access code bleeding across application tiers.

As for MVC4, I am not sure.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**MVC Scaffolding** is working very well for MVC 4. I have been using it for the last weeks in a new  ASP.NET MVC 4 project with Visual Studio 2012 and everything seems to be okay.

This article shows a good example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and.

It is open-source, to check the changesets, that is the link: http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets